# Differential on interval

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have 3 function:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}0& \text{ if } -1000\le x \le 0\\ x& \text{ if } 0\le x \le 1000.\end{cases}$$

$$g(x) = \begin{cases}0& \text{ if } -1000\le x \le 0\\ 0.001x^2& \text{ if } 0\le x \le 1000.\end{cases}$$

$$h(x) = \begin{cases}0& \text{ if } -1000\le x \le 0\\ 0.000001x^3& \text{ if } 0\le x \le 1000.\end{cases}$$

I have to show that f(x) is not differentiable on the the interval (-1000,1000) and g(x),h(x) is. How do I do that? Can anyone help? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint : Compare the left and the right derivate of $f(x)$ at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Left Hand Derivative of f(x) at x=0 is 0 while Right Hand Derivative is 1. Thus f(x) is not differentiable at x=0. Similarly you can check for g(x) & h(x) where you will find the Right Hand Derivative at x=0 to be 0.